# Issue with raspberry pi serial port

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, printers

I'm using raspberry pi 2 to control 2 types of printers. I found at this site how to send serial commands in hexadecimal format using python, like:

```
cmdTest=b"\x12\x02\x42"
ser.write(cmdTest)
```

This code works true for one printer but fail for another!
knowing that:

I test both devices using a normal computer and both works.

Both are from same manufacturer (ELTRA*SISTEMI*).

I am using the appropriate commands for every printer

I am specifying the correct baud rate knowing that both are of the same baud rate.

Comment: did you get response or error message from the printer?

Comment: No I get no response, there is a led that flash on when recieving commands, and it never flash. But a led in rs232 convertor is flashing on means it recieve commands but never transmitting it to the printer. Although I'm using the same cable I used to connect the working printer.

Comment: What's your definition of a  *"normal computer"*?

Comment: Please specify the commands that you are using..

Comment: Sorry sawdust :) I know it is a wrong word, raspberry is also a normal computer, but I were mean a desktop or laptop not a micro controller.

Comment: The commands are correct the problem is something related to the serial convertor I were using. Now I used a usb to serial convertor instead of a shield convertor and it works great with same code and same commands. Although it worked, I'm still confused why the a printer worked with RS232 shield and other not.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved, Although something still not clear.
The commands were correct the problem is something related to the serial convertor I were using. Now I used a usb to serial convertor instead of a shield convertor and it works great with same code and same commands. Although it worked, I'm still confused why a printer worked with RS232 shield and other not.